# How to store values in a array inside other function

Tags: arrays, c, function, c99

I've started learning C. I'm doing functions right now.
In these exercise they want me to ask for a value that means an error. If they input the number 8, it  means that it's error "8", if value 6 error is "6"(the error part don't matter). I should call a fuction to store this error and other functio to go trought it and see if any value ("error"), Was stored more than once.
I started by asking for how many errors the user will introduce, soo I could run a loop "N" times to ask for the value.
Then I made a function called aviso(means warning ~ error), to store them in a array.
When the function reaches the last value of "error" it calls other function to count if the numbers are repeated .

My main problem right now is how to store the values in the array and keeping them. Every time I introduce a value in the array it happear other like: array[0] = 7 the output  is like array[0] = -32134123.
So my function is not storing any  value in the array.

My code is very messy right now, please any suggestions are welcome since I'm clearly very new at C.
Excuse my code I just "try" to translate some names to english.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Function Incomplete since my array is not sotring values 
int alertwarning(int array[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++){
    }
}

int warning(int num , int n, int count){
    int check = count - 1 , array[n];
    if(count <= n){
        array[check] = num;
    }
    if(count  == n){
            alertwarning(array);
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++){
    }
    }
    return  0;
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num, count, n;
    printf("|Warning System!|(Only values equal or above 0 are acepted!)\n");
    
    printf("\nIntroduce how many warnings are being stored: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);    
    fflush(stdin);
    int array[n];

    do{
        
        
        printf("\nIntroduce a value equal or bigger then 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        //system("cls");        
        if(num < 0){
            printf("|Please introduce  a valuer equal or above 0!|\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else if(num >= 0){
        count++;
        }
        warning(num, n, count);         

    }while( count < n);
        return 0;
}
```

`

I tried to store the array inside the main() and it worked but it was required to do it in other function to complete this exercise. I don't know if the function just don't save the values of the last time it was called.

how to store the values in the array and keeping them. Every time I introduce a value in the array it happear other like: array[0] = 7 the output  is like array[0] = -32134123.
So my function is not storing any  value in the array.

I tried printf to see where I go wrong with the few knowledge I own. When they are called they work but the next time they are called I think they reset the values of the array.

Comment: `sizeof(array)` in the function is not the size of the array, it's just the size of a pointer.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` does not make any sense and is undefined behaviour

Comment: `else if(num >= 0){` - Surely you do not need the `if` as this is always going to be true

Comment: `array[n];` in `int warning()` is a local array. It is not the array from main and it is destroyed on function exit. To communicate an array to a function, pass a pointer to its first element and the number of entries in the array as parameters.

Comment: To clarify my  comment, I mean the `alertwarning` function since an array passed as argument will *decay* to a pointer to its first element.